# module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook, artificial-intelligence

I'm stuck with that problem AttributeError It says module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects', as far as I checked, it only happens to Import keras, all other models are normal, anyone know how to fix this? I really need help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBdtP.png)

Comment: The version of the notebook server is: 6.3.0

Comment: tf.__version__ = 2.5.0
python_version() = 3.8.8

Comment: if you have TensorFlow > 2, import keras as `import tensorflow.keras` .

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs due to the version incompatibility of `tensorflow` and `keras`.

Use this to solve this issue:

```py
pip uninstall tf-nightly
pip uninstall tf-estimate-nightly
pip install tensorflow –upgrade –force-reinstall
```

If the above commands do not help, install `3.8` version of python and `2.4` version of `Tensorflow` and `keras`